# Морфема и семантика

Tags: семантика, морфемика

Есть два слова: **допрос** и **опрос** - каждое из них обладает полнотой значения, и эти значения пересекаются:

*1)**Опрос** обвиняемого, свидетеля и т. д. для выяснения чего-л.
2)Произведение официального **допроса**.*

Следовательно, почему в одном случае авторы выделяют приставку (**о**прос), а в другом - нет (допрос)? Не вижу для этого никаких оснований.

---

Если вы скажете, что должна быть связь с глаголом "просить", то я скажу так: эту связь восстановить можно, пусть и не очень логичную (в любом случае она найдется, да и не везде нам нужно искать связь с корнем, возьмем хотя бы "**с**вергнуть/**низ**вергнуть")

Comment: Потому что с приставкой "до" означало бы закончить опрос (*домыть; доиграть; дописать*).

Comment: @oleedd Если следовать вашей логике, то тогда придем к тому, что эти слова вообще никак не связаны по смыслу...а это далеко не так. И то и другое относится к "спрашиванию".

Comment: Связаны, но вам же нужна причина. Приставки несут определённый стандартный смысл. Может, не вывели приставку "до" с таким значением (она должна быть и в других словах). Да и не очень понятно, какое здесь может быть у неё значение. Лингвисты могут менять свои взгляды. Словари исправляются, меняются.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Кто правее**

Разбор слова по составу —  это такая область, где во многом проявляется **волевое решение**, а решают задачу  лингвисты часто по-разному. Так что же, надо искать того, кто правее?

Думаю, что нет. В Интернете на учебных сайтах обычно отражается **общепринятое**  на текущий момент решение. С другой стороны, это делается не просто так, но имеет объяснение по сути. И вот этот момент особенно интересен.

**P.S.** Нашла Школьный словообразовательный **(гнездовой!)** словарь 1978 года Тихонова (на бумаге). Там **два разных гнезда** для  глаголов: (1) ***просить — о/просить*** и (2) ***допросить***.  И какой тогда смысл рассматривать разные точки зрения в дальнейшем, если сейчас пришли к тому же выводу. Чтобы изменить что-либо, нужно иметь очень убедительные доводы.

**Что могло измениться,** чтобы тот же Тихонов вдруг стал выделять приставку ДО? Есть еще двухтомник: Тихонов А.Н. Словообразовательный словарь русского языка: В 2 т. М.: Рус. яз., 2-е изд. 1990. Около 145 000 слов.  Интересно, как решается задача там, когда он был правее,  в ранних своих книгах или потом? https://www.slovorod.ru/der-tikhonov/index.html  Следует особо отметит, какое большое значение он придавал именно **ГНЕЗДОВЫМ словарям**.

А здесь перечень всех словарей Тихонова https://mytashkent.uz/2017/11/20/sluzhenie-slovu-leksicheskoe-nasledie-a-n-tihonova/

Или нужно предлагать **разные варианты разбора**? По Тихонову (1), по Тихонову (2), по Морковкину и т.д.

Когда есть **РАЗНЫЕ ТОЧКИ ЗРЕНИЯ** и пользователь не знает, **куда голову повернуть**, как правильно ответить (на экзамене, например), то надо себя **подстраховать** хотя бы тем, что знаешь о разных решениях.  И надо иметь собственное **обоснованное мнение**, если об этом спросят: почему приставка ДО входит или не входит в состав корня.

**Решение по сути**

Здесь я согласна с уже данным ответом, сама бы ответила примерно так же. Поэтому просто добавлю немного информации.

1. Итак, **ДОПРОС** - это **судебный термин** (в обычной  речи у него переносное значение):

**ДОПРОС**; м. Опрос **обвиняемого**, свидетеля и т.п. для выяснения обстоятельств дела, преступления и т.п. Д. свидетелей. Протокол допроса. Вызвать на д. Вести д. Подвергнуть допросу. Д. с пристрастием (с применением мер физического воздействия). // Разг. Настойчивое, подробно расспрашивание. Нам учинили настоящий д.

2. К такому выводу можно прийти и без словаря, просто при сравнении значений **приставок О и ДО.** Надо сказать, что у многозначных приставок всегда можно найти **центральное** значение. **Приставка О** — это распространение действия вокруг предмета, а **приставка ДО** — направленность на определенную цель с завершением действия.
3. Это видно при сравнении слов ***опрос*** и ***допрос***. Опросить кого-либо можно **по разным вопросам**, в том числе делается опрос свидетелей. Но это всего лишь опрос.

А вот допрашивают уже **обвиняемых**. Формулировка обвинения есть, так что следователи  имеют  определенную **цель**: пусть сознается, а мы ему поможем))

Допрос **свидетелей**? Может быть, конечно. Но этот опрос/допрос тоже целенаправленный.

**Приложение**

**О, приставка** (служит для образования глаг.). 1. Обозначает направленность действия по окружности, **вокруг предмета**, распространение действия на всю поверхность предмета, на все его стороны. Обежать (вокруг дома), огородить, охватить, окопать, оскоблить, осмотреть.  3. Обозначает **распространение** действия на ряд лиц, предметов, охват действием многих лиц, предметов. Обегать, одарить.

**ДО,  приставка**  I. (служит для образования глаг.). 1. Обозначает: доведение действия до его **завершения**, конца; **достижение цели**, предела действия. Дочитать, дошить, доесть, доехать, дожить, доплыть.

Comment: Да, чуток ошибся насчет допроса свидетелей, да может быть, но он регламентирован и протоколируется не только текст, кроме того если судить по кино, есть всякие ритуалы, например в США, когда дают клятву говорить только правду и тп. Но я бы не согласился что допрос - это опрос, мне кажется это ошибка, допрос/опрос - это именно термины, причем разные. Если смотреть формулировки законов или материалы по криминалистике, там никогда их не путают.

Comment: Да, вы правы. Допрос свидетелей – звучит странно, так что похоже на иронию. Все тонкости судебной практики мы не всегда знаем, а опрос и допрос – специальные термины. Но вот в словарь общепринятой лексики "допрос свидетелей" как-то плохо вписывается))

Comment: Я исправил ответ, всё-таки *свидетель*, тоже специфический термин, опрашивают очевидцев, а допрашивают свидетелей. Чёткость юридической терминологии регламентирована и теоретически неверно составленный протокол не будет считаться документом.

Comment: Да, спасибо вам, очень все познавательно, хотя и не так просто. Вот как внимательно надо относиться к словам.

Answer (score 2):

Не могу пока спрашивать через комментарии, вынужден спросить здесь.

> Achy:”почему в одном случае авторы выделяют приставку (опрос), а в
> другом - нет (допрос)?”

Кто из *авторов* не выделяет приставку в слове «допрос»?

> Angry: “Например, Тихонов, да и Потиха тоже”.

Ну, так Потиха-то не выделяет приставку и в слове «опрос». Видимо, считает эти слова разошедшимися по семантике.

А вот Тихонов… В его «*Морфемно-орфографическом словаре*» (который используют *учебные* интернет-сайты) действительно в слове «опрос» приставка выделяется, а в слове «допрос» – нет. Но, к сожалению, в этом словаре так много неточностей, что относиться к нему надо с большой осторожностью, перепроверяя, по возможности, сомнительные слова по другим словарям Тихонова.

Практически в одно время с «*Морфемно-орфографическим*» Тихоновым был выпущен «*Словарь-справочник по русскому языку*» (1997). И вот в этом словаре приставка в слове «допрос» Тихоновым выделена: ***до/прос/***.

См.:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**P.S.**

Выделяется приставка в слове «допрос» и в «Большом универсальном словаре русского языка» под ред. Морковкина…

Comment: Например, Тихонов, да и Потиха тоже.

Comment: Интернет тоже не выделяет https://kartaslov.ru/разбор-слова-по-составу/допрос  Наверное, слово в судебную терминологию ушло. Приставка ДО с приобрела специфическое значение.

Comment: @Sharon понятно, что "допрос" лишь отчасти связано со словом "просить", но ведь "допрос" мы можем трактовать через "опрос", которое имеет другую приставку и тесно связано с допросом по смыслу. Почему тогда в одном случае мы выделяем эту приставку, а в другом  - нет, рассматривая лишь опрощенный корень. Подход ведь должен быть един во всем. И таких слов очень много: отдохнуть-передохнуть/ возобладать-преобладать и т.д.

Comment: Не слышал ни разу про универсальный словарь. Ваш ответ мне тоже очень понравился, и я даже за него проголосовал.

Answer (score 1):

О+прос - это вокруг вопроса, проблемы, *опрос очевидцев*, показание очевидцев, без вторжение в личное пространство. Хотя если *очевидец* говорит что-то относящееся к делу, то его слова [*протоколируются*](https://www.consultant.ru/document/cons_doc_LAW_34481/2d6f437c5056bf106c05fef784cec9ee15521d7c/) и он может стать [*свидетелем*](https://www.consultant.ru/document/cons_doc_LAW_34481/2d6f437c5056bf106c05fef784cec9ee15521d7c/), и нести юр ответственность и быть обязанным говорить по делу в рамках права.

До+прос - активное завершение цели просьбы/вопроса, так же как бить-добить, рвать-дорвать и тд, т е завершить/завершать некое действие, дойти/доводить до цели. Подозреваемых - допрашивают, допрос предусматривает ответы на конкретные вопросы, и все ответы, а также отказ дать ответ будет запротоколирован, в отличие от опроса, который добровольный. От опроса отказаться можно, потому что четкой цели опроса нет, есть поиск этой цели, с которым могут помочь, а от допроса отказаться нельзя, кроме того запротоколированным может быть и невербальный язык - поведение при допросе, допросы могут записывать на видео.

А еще есть объ+яснение, об - имеет более четкую форму, форма чего-то ясного. Объяснительную пишут пострадавшие, которые ставят тот самый вопрос, на который ищут ответ следователи. То есть объяснительная предполагает конкретизацию формы, допрос предполагает выявление этой конкретизированной формы и связи с подозреваемыми, а опрос - это не поиск чего-то конкретного, а наоборот поиск дополнительных моментов, неучтенных первым и вторым, которые могли бы лучше конкретизировать проблему или цели/способы её решения.

*Правка:

Я изменил неточности так как:

Есть термин *допрос свидетелей*, но есть и *опрос очевидцев*. Но [очевидец не всегда свидетель, как и свидетель не всегда очевидец](https://moluch.ru/archive/434/95142/#:%7E:text=%D0%9E%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%86%20%E2%80%94%20%D1%8D%D1%82%D0%BE%20%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%BE,%D0%B8%20%D1%82.%20%D0%B4.).

Насчет допрос - это опрос на в ряде словарей, например Ожегова и Ефремовой на [лексикографии](https://lexicography.online/explanatory/%D0%B4/%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81#:%7E:text=%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%CC%81%D1%81%2C%20%2D%D0%B0%2C%20%D0%BC.%20%D0%9E%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%20%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%8F%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE) .. я не соглашусь, потому что это неточность ведущая к неверным выводам, есть разница в употреблении допрос и опрос, а слова номинативы *свидетель/подозреваемый*, **не являются определяющим условием**(см. внизу разницу с Далем) для проведения *допроса/опроса*, подозреваемого тоже можно опросить - спросить как ему живется в заключении и тд., задать вопросы "вне протокола".

[Допрос свидетелей - ни разу не становится опросом.](https://www.consultant.ru/document/cons_doc_LAW_34481/2d6f437c5056bf106c05fef784cec9ee15521d7c/)

Если посмотреть у Даля, то у него есть две формулировки:

*Допрашивать - допросить кого, делать допрос, расспрашивать, требовать отчета, ответа.*

*Опрашивать, опросить кого, допрашивать по праву; расспрашивать многих о чем и узнавать.*

Видно, что у Даля *опрос* - это "*допрос по праву"*, но это уже *не просто* **допрос**, а то, что приобретает **значение в рамках закона**. Так вот **ПРАВО**, *в отличии от свидетеля/подозреваемого*, **является определяющим для допроса/опроса**.

**Допрос - это принуждение к ответу на вопрос по праву, в рамках закона, судебный термин**,

*а опрос может быть и без права, но не наоборот.*

**Опрос может стать допросом, а допрос опросом - нет.**

допрашивают когда требуют ответа на конкретный вопрос, знают что спрашивают.

а опрашивают - имеют право(если это касается органов) или просто "интересуются" положением дел, не обладая знанием, узнают, не знают, о чем хотят спросить.